# Impersonate Google Cloud Patform user through OAuth2.0 flow

Tags: security, google-cloud-platform, oauth-2.0, oauth, google-oauth

I want to set up an OAuth2.0 flow for users that have access to GCP.

The user will login to a web app.

Then, the OAuth2.0 flow will need to ask for the consent that will allow the app to perform things on their behalf, based on their permissions.

Therefore, the scopes that need to be requested should be those that cover their actual permissions on GCP.

Is something like that possible when it comes to OAuth2.0 and GCP?

Answer (score 0):

Had you seen?  https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2

Looks like that might address your question.

Separately from that link --> Yes that is something that could be done.  You login via OAuth, and once authenticated that service can use GCP Service Accounts https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-accounts to work with GCP Services.

Answer (score 0):

A user can be granted permission to impersonate a service account.

A service account can be granted permission to impersonate a user account via Domain Wide Delegation (Google Workspace).

A user cannot impersonate another user. There is no mechanism to grant the required permissions.

Answer (score 0):

In a GCP project you can access Google APIs using these types of credentials:

1. API keys
2. OAuth 2.0 client IDs
3. service accounts

So, to answer you question, using OAuth 2.0 in GCP is certainly possible.

However, without knowing what **data** your application needs to access, it's hard to tell if it's more appropriate to use a service account or an OAuth 2.0 client. In a GCP project, if you go to `APIs and services > Credentials > CREATE CREDENTIALS > Help me choose`, a wizard will guide you through the process of creating the most appropriate credential for each authentication scenario:

[image: The "Help me choose" wizard when creating a new credential in Google Cloud]

Lastly, when you say this:

> for users that have access to GCP

Do you mean that these users have a Google account that can access the Google APIs used in your project? If that's the case, and your project doesn't need to access user's data, then a service account might be a better choice than an OAuth 2.0 consent screen. I think you *could* let a service account impersonate a user via Domain Wide Delegation, but please keep in mind that [Google itself discourages this feature](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/best-practices-for-securing-service-accounts#domain-wide-delegation).

See also [Create access credentials](https://developers.google.com/workspace/guides/create-credentials).